# Reload JS dynamically

Tags: javascript

I am currently working on a page that displays a graph which can be modified by clicking on some buttons. To display the graph, I use amCharts script (see http://amcharts.com). The code that displays the chart is generated dynamically using ASP. However, I have a problem when reloading the graph when the user clicks on one of the buttons. I try to clear the div in which the graph is written and load the new JS script using :

```
document.getElementById("flashcontent").innerHTML = ""; 
var head = document.getElementsByTagName("HEAD")[0];
var node = document.createElement('script');
node.type = 'text/javascript';
node.async = true;
node.src = strQueryString;  
head.appendChild(node);
```

I verified a lot of time that the `strQueryString` variable is right and the Firebug says that the right script is loaded. However, the div is cleared but my JS is not executed. Note : all my JS is loaded dynamically using a similar code when the page is loaded.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

It might depend on the script you are trying to execute, ie, it might just be functions that are not called, but just defined.
You may also want to try a different approach, which is to make an AJAX requests after load, which returns JavaScript that then is executed by the browser.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem ! It was due to an event on the AmCharts side, namely the AmCharts.ready function for those who are interested.